# Can Skype be run as SharePoint WebPart?

Tags: web-part, spfx, client-side-rendering

I am looking into remote monitoring options for the disabled.

And have to decide on Google, Microsoft or Amazon technology

Would like to run (end-user is not capable of operating devices):

- Run a SharePoint webpart (device is always logged in)
- from a remote location trigger Skype
- have a conversation
- end Skype

Comment: it may have to be a SharePoint visual webpart or SharePoint app, using the Skype SDK. It's for Android, but should work the same way, joining meetings, chatting, etc.: https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-android-app-sdk-samples/tree/master/GuestMeetingJoin